# How to remove <li> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is my HTML code:

```
<form name="package_type_documents"  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="hor-form">    
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="answer-block" id="doc_title">
            <a href="#" class="c-gray-btn c-add-btn" name="add_more_title" id="add_more_title" onclick="add_title(); return false;"><span>Add More Documents</span></a>
            <ol>
                                          <li id="ttl1" class="ptdoc">
                <li class="ans_li">
                  <span class="num-block">1&nbsp;</span><span class="num-block reqd">*</span>
                  <label>Document Title</label>
                  <input type="text" name="pt_doc_title[1]" id="pt_doc_title_1" value="Prabhakar Bhosale" />
                </li>
                <li class="ans_li">
                  <span class="num-block">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class="num-block reqd">&nbsp;</span>
                  <label>Document File</label>
                  <p class="uploadBtn"><input type="file" name="document_file_name_1" id="document_file_name_1"/>
                  </p>
                </li>

                                                  <li class="ans_li">
                  <a href="package_type_documents.php?op=download&pt_id=5&pt_doc_id=19" style="font-size:small;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;prabhakar_bhosale.docx</a>
                </li>                 
                                                                  <li class="ans_li">                
                  <input type="checkbox" name="delete_file_1" id="delete_file_1" class="custom-check" />
                  <label for="show">Delete document</label>
                </li>


                <input type="hidden" name="pt_doc_id[0]" value="19" />
                                  <input type="hidden" name="pt_doc_old_file_iname[0]" value="prabhakar_bhosale.docx" />  

              </li>
                                    </ol>
            <a href="#" class="c-gray-btn c-add-btn" name="add_more_title" id="add_more_title" onclick="add_title(); return false;"><span>Add More Documents</span></a>
            <p class="fade">Note * (Image size should be less then 1 mb and allowed image types are jpg, jpeg, gif, png .)</p>
          </div>         
        </li>       
        <li>          
          <p class="last">
            <input id="saveForm" class="c-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
            <input type="button" class="c-gray-btn" name="back" value="Back" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/package_type/view_package_type.php?page=1'" />
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  </form>
```

Following is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function delete_title(field) {
  $('li'+'#'+field).remove();  
}
</script>
```

The following code is not deleting the concerned

. I tried many tricks but still it's not removing. Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: How exactly are you calling `delete_title`?

Comment: what do you want to delete.

Comment: how is `delete_title` called... and what is the value passed for fields

Comment: also your html doesn't looks to be valid since you have `li` inside `li`

Comment: I can't explain the whole scenario here as it's too large to explain. Can anyone tell me whether the code I've wiritten is correct to delete the <li> having the same Id which I'm passing? If that is resolved then my whole issue will get resolve.

Comment: don't use li you use `ID` and id always unique, for share your code use http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

check demo and check how call function

```
function delete_title(field) {
  $("#"+field).remove();  
}

delete_title('ttl1');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkv63/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one is Javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('id');
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you must be having ids unique for li element. And For deleting element using id. You can use:

```
$('#'+field).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').remove();
```

this Will remove all the li elements

and below code will remove specific Li element from UL.

```
`$('#li_yourId').remove();`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete `<li>` element with given id then you can write:

```
$('#'+field).remove();
```

No need to write li.